# Merge a several files with the name of the file in the first column

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to merge several files into one, adding the name of each file in the first column. I already put the header and the file name, but i do not want the whole file name
Thank you

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.txt
do
  head -1 $i | awk '{OFS="\t";print "Sample", $0}' > outputprueba.txt
break
done
for a in *bla.txt
do
        sed 1d $a | awk -v x="'"$a"'" '{OFS="\t";print x, $0}' >> outputprueba.txt
done
```

```
I expect this output:
Sample  Chr Start   End
File1   chr1    10318652    10318652
File1   chr1    10322054    10322054
File2   chr1    132887500   132887500
File2   chr1    132888208   132888208

but the actual output is:
Sample  Chr Start   End
'File1_annotated_fastq_blablabla.txt'   chr1    10318652    10318652
'File1_annotated_fastq_blablabla.txt'   chr1    10322054    10322054
'File2_annotated_fastq_blablabla.txt'   chr1    132887500   132887500
'File2_annotated_fastq_blablabla.txt'   chr1    132888208   132888208
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include the sample input that would produce your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```
awk '
BEGIN  { OFS="\t" }
NR==1  { print "Sample", $0 }
FNR==1 { fname=FILENAME; sub(/_.*/,"",fname); next }
{ print fname, $0 }
' *bla.txt
```